# Error when constructing Gremlin traversal using Lambda function

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a vertex that is set with properties `startDate` and `endDate`:

```
Date start = new Date();
Date end = Date.from(start.toInstant().plusSeconds(600));
g.V(8L).property("startDate", start).property("endDate", end).next();
```

Now I want to compute the difference `endDate-startDate` and I could do that with `sack()`:

```
g.V(8L)
    .sack(Operator.assign).by(values("endDate").map(it -> ((Date)it.get()).getTime()))
    .sack(Operator.minus).by(values("startDate").map(it -> ((Date)it.get()).getTime()))
    .sack()
```

However, this does not work if the traversal is sent remotely.

By converting the Lambda into Lambda.function(), the below traversal works remotely:

```
String funcGetTime = "v -> ((Date)v.get()).getTime()";
g.V(8L)
        .sack(Operator.assign).by(values("endDate").map(Lambda.function(funcGetTime)))
        .sack(Operator.minus).by(values("startDate").map(Lambda.function(funcGetTime)))
        .sack()
```

However, the traversal no longer works in my in-memory graph local setup. The error message is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[8]->[PropertiesStep([endDate],value), LambdaMapStep(lambda[v -> ((Date)v.get()).getTime()])]
```

My question is: Is there a traversal that does the same thing (calculate the diff between endDate and startDate) that can work for both local and remote? I need it since my unit tests are run locally with in-memory graph while during running, my application invokes the traversal by connecting to a remote graph.

The reason I have to compute the diff in the traversal (instead of doing in my application) is because I want to use this diff further in the traversal later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gremlin does not yet have datetime operators that can help you with this and as you've found a remote lambda won't evaluate in the same fashion as a local one. The remote one requires that the entire traversal be evaluated in the `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine`, which basically takes the Gremlin `Bytecode`, runs it through the `GroovyTranslator` and then evaluates the whole thing as a script. I can simulate that in the Gremlin Console as follows:

```
gremlin> evaluate(GroovyTranslator.of("g").translate(g.V().map(Lambda.function("v -> v"))).script)
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
```

If you need the remote to work the same as local, I can't think of any workarounds short of either the above approach or by storing your date as long (perhaps as a form of denormalization) so that you can do the calculations directly without having to the `DateTime` conversion. Hopefully, Gremlin will get better date operations in future versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and suggestion. Maybe using type long should work in my case. My application will convert it to displayed as Date.